# How to download and compile a source from an apache project if I have the link (svn)?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, apache, svn

Lets say I have this link here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/dotcmis/trunk/ and I would like to download and compile the source on my windows. What is todo?

There are a lot folders, classes and some bats. I could download them via browser, one by one - but im sure this is not the way how I should do that. Do I need a special svn tool? And after that? I just have to load the porject in Visual Studio and thats it? I dont thinks so. Any step by step guides or ideas? Thank you

Comment: A local SVN client - e.g. TortoiseSVN from http://tortoisesvn.net - will make this easy.

Comment: ok was easier than I thought. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [download page](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html):

> DotCMIS requires the .NET Framework version 3.5 or higher. It does not depend on anything else.

So yes, you should be able to do an `svn checkout` using your favorite SVN client (for example from a commandline tool, from [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) or from [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/downloads)), build the project and profit.

If you're just interested in using the client, the download page also links to the binaries you can just download and add a reference to.

Answer (score 1):

Install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (or another SVN client) and give it the connection settings.
Then do a full checkout into a folder on your local machine

Also this tool [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) comes with an integrated add-in for Visual Studio that allows you to perform some operations directly inside the VS IDE.